# Composer update or require not pulling latest release

Tags: composer-php

My composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "insenseanalytics/laravel-user-audit-trails": "^1.0"
}
```

Output of composer diagnose:

```
Checking composer.json: WARNING
require.insenseanalytics/nova-impersonate-tool : unbound version constraints (*) should be avoided
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys:
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version: OK
Composer version: 1.7.2
PHP version: 7.1.18
PHP binary path: /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.1/7.1.18/bin/php
```

When I run this command:

```
composer update
```

Composer pulls in v1.0 and not v1.0.1. [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/insenseanalytics/laravel-user-audit-trails) correctly shows v1.0.1 as the latest release but somehow it doesn't recognize it.

When I run this command:

```
composer show insenseanalytics/laravel-user-audit-trails
```

It outputs

```
name     : insenseanalytics/laravel-user-audit-trails
descrip. : User audit trails for Laravel Eloquent.
keywords : Audit, audit trails, laravel, user trails
versions : * v1.0
type     : library
license  : MIT License (MIT) (OSI approved) https://spdx.org/licenses/MIT.html#licenseText
source   : [git] https://github.com/insenseanalytics/laravel-user-audit-trails.git 09256e522240f29b7b214a9f15dc5f62bb8f02a7
dist     : [zip] https://api.github.com/repos/insenseanalytics/laravel-user-audit-trails/zipball/09256e522240f29b7b214a9f15dc5f62bb8f02a7 09256e522240f29b7b214a9f15dc5f62bb8f02a7
names    : insenseanalytics/laravel-user-audit-trails

autoload
psr-4
Insense\LaravelUserAuditTrails\ => src/

requires
illuminate/database ~5.5.0|~5.6.0
illuminate/support ~5.5.0|~5.6.0

requires (dev)
doctrine/dbal ~2.6
orchestra/testbench ~3.5.0|~3.6.0
phpunit/phpunit ^6.0|^7.0
```

But the above output doesn't show the latest tag v1.0.1. I am also the author of the package I'm trying to pull in but I don't seem to understand what's wrong here? The package composer.json does not have a version entry

Answer (score 2):

It seems that latest release breaks backwards compatibility. [Official docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md)

**Caret Version Range (^)#**

The **^** operator behaves very similarly but it sticks closer to semantic versioning, and will always allow non-breaking updates. For example ^1.2.3 is equivalent to >=1.2.3 <2.0.0 as none of the releases until 2.0 should break backwards compatibility. For pre-1.0 versions it also acts with safety in mind and treats ^0.3 as >=0.3.0 <0.4.0.

This is the recommended operator for maximum interoperability when writing library code.

Example: ^1.2.3

Comment: I see so what would you recommend to use? Is `~` better?

Comment: I recommed you to put the version that is necessary with the ^ symbol. For more info better to read docs.

Comment: This is strange, now everything is installing properly using the original composer settings (^1.0). I dont know how

Comment: Laravel does not follow semver, it is pretty bad idea to use `^` for constraints for Laravel dependencies, since it is allow BC breaking updates.

Comment: @Paras It could be some caching issues.

Comment: I ran composer clearcache earlier. Don't know what this black magic is!